# angular 2 observable timeout second parameter type

Tags: angular, http, timeout, observable

I am currently trying to make *timeout()* method of Angular 2 Observable work properly, but in all tutorials there is similair code, where the second argument of *timeout()* method is a simple Error:

```
return this.http.get('http://...')
                .timeout(2000, new Error('Timeout exceeded'));
```

But when I copy this code, TypeScript says that the second argument has invalid type and expects to see smth which implements interface *IScheduler*.

One of the ways to solve the problem is to make new class which implements IScheduler interface, but it has functionality I am not familiar with (*now()* method and *Tasks*).

Does anyone know, should I do it in this way or are there another ways to make things work? And what if instead of error I want to place some callback function?

Comment: What about `.timeout(2000, {errorToSend: new Error('Timeout exceeded')});`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, tried it, but it says **Argument of type '{ errorToSend: Error; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IScheduler'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'errorToSend' does not exist in type 'IScheduler'.** And in ReactiveX github they [say](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/commit/98ea3d221e0b1c2da66e09b525a165abfa7fb460), that it no longer accepts this parameter

Comment: Seems like the docs are not up-to-date. There is no error parameter anymore in https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3e9d5295f118c29193f88ea825902ac359901119/src/operator/timeout.ts#L18 See also https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3e9d5295f118c29193f88ea825902ac359901119/spec/operators/timeout-spec.ts#L89

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`timeout`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-timeout) does not take an `Error` as a parameter. If a timeout occurs it will throw a [`TimeoutError`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/util/TimeoutError.js~TimeoutError.html).

If you want to throw a particular type of error, you could use the [`timeoutWith` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-timeoutWith) to do something like this:

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeoutWith';

return this.http
  .get('http://...')
  .timeoutWith(2000, Observable.throw(new Error('Boom!')));
```

Comment: Tried this with 0 sec timeout but error didn't show up

Comment: It works just fine, for me (using `timeoutWith`). Are you sure you've subscribed to the observable? Without a subscription, nothing will happen.

Comment: yes, the Observable returned from `this.http.get(...)` is subscribed in the service. Maybe it can be more obvious if I could console log smth instead of throwing error

Comment: Well, you also need either use a `catch` operator or pass an `error` callback to the `subscribe` call. Otherwise, it'll be unhandled - and should show up in the console - but that's it; there's nothing tricky. It's working for me with Angular 2.4.10 and RxJS 5.2.0.